# Could not find class 'oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer'

Tags: android

Recently, I encountered a problem,My android app always stopped unexpectedly and some errors are printed on the log.In fact, I do not know how to debug my program base on logcat which everybody I asked for help wanted.please help me!

Here's my log.

```
04-22 11:57:20.653: W/dalvikvm(346): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 41 (Loauth/signpost/commonshttp/CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;) in LOAuth4Sina/com/AuthActivity;
04-22 11:57:20.653: D/dalvikvm(346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000f
04-22 11:57:20.673: D/dalvikvm(346): VFY: dead code 0x0011-0039 in LOAuth4Sina/com/AuthActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
04-22 11:57:20.673: I/dalvikvm(346): Could not find method oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider.setOAuth10a, referenced from method OAuth4Sina.com.AuthActivity.onNewIntent
04-22 11:57:20.693: W/dalvikvm(346): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 41: Loauth/signpost/OAuthProvider;.setOAuth10a (Z)V
04-22 11:57:20.693: D/dalvikvm(346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0010
04-22 11:57:20.733: W/dalvikvm(346): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 44 (Loauth/signpost/exception/OAuthMessageSignerException;)
04-22 11:57:20.733: W/dalvikvm(346): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x68
04-22 11:57:20.733: W/dalvikvm(346): VFY:  rejected LOAuth4Sina/com/AuthActivity;.onNewIntent (Landroid/content/Intent;)V
04-22 11:57:20.766: W/dalvikvm(346): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0068
04-22 11:57:20.766: W/dalvikvm(346): VFY:  rejected LOAuth4Sina/com/AuthActivity;.onNewIntent (Landroid/content/Intent;)V
04-22 11:57:20.766: W/dalvikvm(346): Verifier rejected class LOAuth4Sina/com/AuthActivity;
04-22 11:57:20.766: W/dalvikvm(346): Class init failed in newInstance call (LOAuth4Sina/com/AuthActivity;)
04-22 11:57:20.785: D/AndroidRuntime(346): Shutting down VM
04-22 11:57:20.785: W/dalvikvm(346): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346): java.lang.VerifyError: OAuth4Sina.com.AuthActivity
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-22 11:57:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```